# calculate remaining point, expiring points for membership loyalty program

Tags: php, laravel

I have data on database like

[image]

where
id = trasactionID
type = transaction type (EARN = user get point from store, REDEEM = user use point)
expiredAt = point expiration (EARN point has 1 year before it expired)

my problem is I need to calculate

1. remaining point for the user. eg. If I query on this day (19 feb 2024) how many point remaining. (expired point should not be calculated)
2. Expiring point (this month)

this is my php function

```html
public function calculateRemainingPoints($memberId)
    {
        // Fetch all transactions for the memberId
        $transactions = Transaction::where('memberId', $memberId)->orderBy('created_at')->get();

        // Initialize total points
        $totalPoints = 0;

        // Process each transaction
        foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
            if ($transaction->type == 'EARN') {
                // Check if the EARN points are not expired
                $expiredAt = Carbon::parse($transaction->expiredAt);
                $currentDate = Carbon::now();
                if ($expiredAt->gt($currentDate)) {
                    // Accumulate EARN points
                    $totalPoints += $transaction->points;
                }
            } elseif ($transaction->type == 'REDEEM') {
                // Deduct REDEEM points
                $totalPoints -= $transaction->points;
            }
        }

        return $totalPoints;
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are facing.

Comment: You've created a very inefficient algorithm, which also contains a bug. Points that where valid in the past, and redeemed then, are not counted now when they have expired. Why not simply store a "current points count" with the user? Then you only need to use your algorithm when the points need to be recounted. Of course you have to debug it first.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you for you anwser, I have change way to calculate remaing points. and look like it more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be a lot easier than you thought.

Considering `points` could be negative or positive numbers depending on the type field. what about simply running a single DB query like this:

```sql
SELECT memberId, SUM(points) AS points_remaining
FROM your_table
WHERE expiredAt IS NULL
GROUP BY memberId
```

If the `points` are all positive numbers, still not a problem:

```sql
SELECT memberId, 
SUM(
    CASE WHEN type = 'REDEEM' THEN -points
    CASE WHEN type = 'EARN' THEN points
    ELSE points
    END
) AS points_remaining
FROM your_table
WHERE expiredAt IS NULL
GROUP BY memberId
```